# How do you get the raw-url for a specific file from the Github API?

Tags: json, api, github, github-api

I can get as far as finding the JSON for the specific repository I'm trying to target but I'm having trouble finding the `raw url`'s of the files.  Does the API have access to this data?

I read the [API Documentation](http://developer.github.com/v3/).  It talked specifically about [media types](http://developer.github.com/v3/media/) for the raw url's.  I thought though, after trying to go through the Repositories documentation that maybe it was the `Git Data` section that might have the answer.

I also referenced this [StackOverflow question](http://goo.gl/arvwG4).  I just can't seem to figure it out.  I just need to find the JSON array and then I'll be able to pull out what I need.  Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As illustrated in this [Go-GiThub project](https://github.com/google/go-github), a media type wouldn't be part of a JSON struct.
It would be part of the request headers:
See [`github/github.go`](https://github.com/google/go-github/blob/34a4afeea7e81dd8b333182da906692d72bdea1a/github/github.go#L162-L163):

```
mediaTypeV3      = "application/vnd.github.v3+json"
req.Header.Add("Accept", mediaTypeV3)
```

In your case: `application/vnd.github.v3.raw`